# how to get access set of values from html source to javascript for processing

Tags: javascript, html

I have set of values in html source coming from my template.

It looks like

```
var formValues = {value1 :'Y',  value2:'Y', value3:'N'}
```

How do i access them in my js file for processing.

Within the same source I have another variable

```
var myVar = 'myValue'
```

And I am able to access this var by just calling it in my javascript by myVar.

I have tried like `formValues.value1` but it's not working.

Comment: You mention `formValues.values1`, but your `formValues` has only a `value1`, not `values1`.

Comment: sorry it was just typos. I have corrected it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that will solve the problem, but you have an extra `s` in `formValues.values1` like **@Hunan** mentioned in comment, should be `formValues.value1`.

```js
var formValues = {value1 :'Y',  value2:'Y', value3:'N'}
console.log(formValues.value1); //return Y
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry it was just typos. I have corrected it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `formValues` declared with respect to where you attempt to read it?

[JavaScript has function scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx). I suspect that if you cannot access it, it's likely either within another function or is declared after you are looking for it.